# Can I build a CoreAPI JS client from DRF and inject it into a react project

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, fetch-api, core-api

I'm building a React client and a REST server with Django REST framework, neither of which are something I'm particularly good at.
Anyway, on the client side, I find myself writing various calls to fetch, and managing the endpoints and content types, which seems dumb.
I noticed that I can use CoreAPI to build a schema of my API and somehow automagically make an API client.
Can I, and would it be sensible and straitforward, to somehow autobuild that client and inject it into my app, and then call it.
This sounds nice and feasible, but not sure how to go about it, thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just think of it like your building on top of a 3rd party api. Your data calls will require an additional js library - but can be done.

Answer (score -1):

The best library I have found for writing js client for DRF is https://github.com/tulios/mappersmith